# Example Query Posts Showing the Latest Post with the Featured Image

Tags: query-posts

I have seen the answer on Stack Overflow, "Example Query Posts Showing the Latest Post with the Featured Image".

```
query_posts( 'showposts=1' );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?><h3 class="home link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php 
        the_title(); ?></a></h3><?php
    the_post_thumbnail();
    the_excerpt();
endwhile;
```

But I would like to know how I get latest 5 posts?

Comment: Please post the code that you got from that link. No one is going to search for it through millions of questions :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting most recent post in WordPress have builtin function named `wp_get_recent_posts( $args, $output )`. So let's try with this function to get most recent 5 post

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true );
```

OR

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .        $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
}
    }
```

Here `thumbnail, medium, large, full` is image size for more [Click](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)
But Other few way you can get you post details like

1- `Loop with get_posts()`
 2- `Loop with query_posts()`
 3- `Loop with WP_Query()`

- To modify the default loop, use `query_posts()`
- To modify loops and/or create multiple loops, use `WP_Query()`
- To create static, additional loops, use `get_posts()`

But remember this They do different things, so it depends on the situation:
`wp_reset_query` destroys the previous query and sets up a new query using `wp_reset_postdata`. Best used with query_posts to reset things after a custom query.

`wp_reset_postdat`a restores `global $post` variable to the current post in the default query. Best used with `WP_Query`.

But Best way to customize query post is `WP_Query()`

```
<ul>
        // Define our WP Query Parameters
        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?>`

        // Start our WP Query
        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

            // Display the Post Title with Hyperlink
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

            // Display the Post Featured Image
            <li><?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                } ?></li>

            // Repeat the process and reset once it hits the limit
            <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </ul>
```

if you want to learn more then go there :[Click](https://digwp.com/2011/05/loops/)
and [Click](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Please note, you should **never ever** use `query_posts` to alter the main query. It breaks the main query and reruns the query, so it is also much slower. **ALWAYS** use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query

Comment: @PieterGoosen ya right, i forgot to mention this caution but I mention about Best Practices `WP_Query` for Multiple Query situation.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer bro. I have tried your code with customizing. Finally I have satisfied.